# Mysql activity feed design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, feed

In my app users can create projects (upload their photos/images), appreciate or add to favorites other users projects, write messages, leave comments. And there is also activity feed, where each user can see new comments, new messages, new projects of their friends etc.

Each record in activity feed can be associated with different objects. For example, record of type `new_vote` can be connected to `Vote`, `Project` and `Sender` (who voted). And every records has `owner`. I have following tables (simplistically):

```
feed (id, owner_id, sender_id, project_id, vote_id, message_id, comment_id, type)
projects (id, title)
votes (id, vote)
```

etc.

And I want each record be related to several objects. For example, records of type `new_message` can be related to several messages. So on activity feed page I can show user "Mike wrote you 4 messages". And in my mind it will be:

```
feed (id, type)
projects (id, title)
votes (id, vote)
feeds_projects_relations (feed_id, project_id)
feeds_votes_relations (feed_id, vote_id)
```

and other similar tables.

Is it right design? Are there better ways of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You also may want to consider if you want to include the user photos images data within your database as an separate table with BLOB field because  files on filesystem will not be removed/changed when you rollback your transactions assuming you are using InnoDB.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I'm not sure about this. Images are the main thing on my website, it's the content. And is it good idea to keep all this files in database?

Comment: Could be depens on the application/hardware/MySQL configuration/used storage engine/ .. storing an path in table and file on filesysteem has an advantage this should be faster with writing files but when you need to fetch an file you need to do an database request and an filesystem request based on an path.... if you store the file into the database writing files could be slower vs filesystem but fetching an file is an simple inner join and file stream will be sended to the php client what could be faster... but you really need to benchmark this

Comment: Moreover, when I request image file, python script must fetch it from database and then send it to user. Dont think it fast. And now my server sends files directly.

Comment: Note old documents.. http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0701/0701168.pdf (2006) or http://www.faculty.jacobs-university.de/pbaumann/iu-bremen.de_pbaumann/Papers/blob-report.pdf (2008) database servers are also improving with speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You have designed your database under the assumption that there is a many to many relationship from feed to votes.  Is that true?  I would assume that each vote relates to only one feed.  In that case, instead of a feeds_votes_relations table, just add feed_id to your votes table to point to the feed it is on.

I am also wondering if feed is the right table name.  I think of feed as an aggregate, or group.  Normally you want your tables to hold single objects, like vote or project and name the tables votes or projects.

Comment: I have table `projects` for projects, table `votes` for votes etc. And I keep feed recrods in separate table named `feeds`.

There are cases, where several votes can have relation to feed. For example, 2 users can vote for project and I want show user 
"Mike L. and Jennie K. voted for your project. Votes are: 9.5 from Mike, 7.9 from Jennie".

And there are other records with many2many. Somebody can send me 5 messages, 3 users can add 5 comments for my project etc. 

And I wonder, is it good design?

Comment: @krasulya That still sounds like votes are one to many.  One project can have many votes but each vote is only for one project.

Comment: oh I get it. `Vote` can be in relations with only one `feed`, that's right. But I don't want `vote` model know anything about `feed`. I want `feed` to be independent.